# Is Using a TEMP table to store Global Vars Inefficient?

Tags: t-sql

I know there is not global vars now in T-SQL.

I know an alternative I just learn is you can store them in a temp table and just update them as needed then use the temp table's values

Is this inefficient though for a lot of data?  I mean consider this:

```
    create table #vars (var1 int, var2 bigint, var3 int)

    GO

    insert #vars(0,0,0) -- default to 0

    GO

    Update #vars set var1 = 1
    update #vars set var2 = 4
    update #vars set var3 = 6

    Then use var1, var2, and var 3 in a SQL statement here

    GO

    repeat this process...update and use

GO

...REPEAT
```

so I mean every time I'm sending multiple update calls to SQL Server just to set these? Just seems way inefficient to me in terms of execution plan possiby?  I guess I could run and see but just curious if this is generally a bad practice?

What I was trying to get away from was having to like most people dup these vars out in every GO's SQL statement that I want to batch

Comment: What is the context of execution?  Is this being fired off from an external application?  Would it be possible to wrap all of this in a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm performing a large data load.  So each batch sql statement will create about 10000 records based on the variable values that I set

Comment: Tried to wrap this into an sp.  So I took and declared the variables in the sp and moved my GO T-sql statements to the body.  But when I tried to use those declared variables by setting them in each Go section, it did not recognize the variables

Comment: so I don't know why the declared variables in my stored proc were not global in each GO....I would assume they should be but maybe not with a GO?

Comment: Do you really need to use 'GO' in the first place?  Perhaps a transaction would suit it better?  Also, for bulk loads, is this data coming from a flat file that could be inserted using the bcp utility?  Or a BulkInsert method from code?

Comment: The GO marks the end of a "script" or block, which is executed independently of the other blocks. So DECLARE variables are not valid after any GO statements.

Answer (score 0):

well at least

```
Update #vars set var1 = 1
update #vars set var2 = 4
update #vars set var3 = 6
```

can be changed to

```
Update #vars set var1=1,var2=4,var3=6
```

Comment: I don't think update statements can be structured that way, thats the insert syntax.  But you could do:  Update #vars SET var1=1, var2=4, var3=6